# Using Child nodes for Internet Explorer isn't working?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, row, children

My code works 100% fine on Chrome and what it does is it gets the text and value from in table rows but as soon as it goes to IE it stops working and i have narrowed it down to childNodes here is a quick sample of the code that doesn't work in IE:

```
var t = document.getElementById('tableFull');

for (var i = 1, row; row = t.rows[i]; i++) {

   var tee = t.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].rowIndex;
   var subtractCost =t.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
   var subtractName = t.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

}
```

Anyone know how i can replace the childNodes here for IE?

Answer (score 0):

`.childNodes` also returns Elements of type "CharakterData", for example White Space in your html code. To refer to the actual HTML-Nodes, use the method "`.children`"

[See more information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children)